# Eigen's matrix seems to preserve the memory in the different scope

Tags: c++, scope, eigen, eigen3

The following snippets, I thought that standard output must be the same in the both scope1 and scope2. However, as the results shows there are not. And the result implies that `m` in the scope2 inherits some values from the ones in scope1. I think this is strange because `m` in scoper1 is supposed to has nothing to do with `m` in scope2. Could someone explain why this happens?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Core>
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
  {
    std::cout << "scope1" << std::endl; 
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    std::cout << m << std::endl; 
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    std::cout << m << std::endl; 
  }
  {
    std::cout << "scope2" << std::endl; 
    MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    std::cout << m << std::endl; 
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    std::cout << m << std::endl; 
  }
}
```

output

```
scope1
0 0
0 0
1 2
3 4
scope2
0 2
3 4
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: The first `cout` in each block prints uninitialized variables, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Anything can happen, including the appearance that some values might be "inherited", which they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html#adca6b686dcbf607bd53a8cbe4dfed85c) says:

> Constructs an **uninitialized** matrix with `rows` rows and `cols` columns.

A program that reads [uninitialized data](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.2) has [undefined behaviour](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7).